# How to Create my own Svelte Embed Component

Tags: embed, svelte, sveltekit

Certain platforms like GitBook allow you to insert an embed URL, like https://www.youtube.com/embed/eGUEAvNpz48, and it displays as a component on that website, as seen here:

[image]

I want to create my own embed component using SvelteKit and have it available at some URL, like https://test/embed, that I can plug in to platforms and have it display as a widget, but I'm not sure how to do that.

In simpler forms, my question is, how do I create an embed component like https://www.youtube.com/embed/eGUEAvNpz48 using SvelteKit?

Answer (score 0):

To create embedded content in Svelte, is no different from what you do in  vanilla HTML, you could simply use the [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) element.

Especially for YouTube video, you could make good use of share feature (shown as below)

[image: Click the Share button -> Click Embed]
Click the Share button -> Click Embed

[image: Copy the code that YouTube gave you here to your .svelte file]
Copy the code that YouTube gave you here to your .svelte file

Example

```html
// src/routes/example/+page.svelte
<iframe
    width="560"
    height="315"
    src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/obuyCkotJ_s"
    title="YouTube video player"
    frameborder="0"
    allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
    allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p> welcome to my page </p>
```